# Why cannot I put this card on a UIScrollView correctly？

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I have specified the frame of a Card, why can't I add this card to a scrollView?

**When I try to add it to a UIScrollView, it will just become a withe bar. Cannot display the content(which is a label), or the toolbar(with title and detail and an IconButton).**

*Code for scrollView*

```
eventList = UIScrollView()
    eventList?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (calender?.frame.height)! + (calenderMenu?.frame.height)!, width: ScreenWidth, height: ScreenHeight - (calenderMenu?.frame.height)! - (calender?.frame.height)!)
    eventList?.scrollsToTop = true
    eventList?.isScrollEnabled = true
    eventList?.bounces = true
    eventList?.isPagingEnabled = true
    eventList?.indicatorStyle = .default
    eventList?.contentSize = CGSize(width: ScreenWidth - 20, height: 400)
    eventList?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(eventList!)
```

*Code for Card*

```
signinCard = Card()
    signinCard?.frame = view.bounds

    signinCard?.toolbar = signinToolbar
    signinCard?.toolbarEdgeInsetsPreset = .square3
    signinCard?.toolbarEdgeInsets.bottom = 0
    signinCard?.toolbarEdgeInsets.right = 8

    signinCard?.contentView = contentView
    signinCard?.contentViewEdgeInsetsPreset = .wideRectangle3

    signinCard?.bottomBar = Bar()

    signinCard?.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: ScreenWidth - 20, height: (eventList?.frame.height)! / 2 - 5)
    eventList?.addSubview(signinCard!)
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say can't add it? error or doesnt appear or what?

Comment: when I try to add it to a UIScrollView, it will just become a withe bar. Cannot display the content(which is a label), or the toolbar(with title and detail and an IconButton).

Comment: can you add your implementation of the Card class?

Comment: Card class comes from Cosmicmind's Material framework, you can check is in this website - https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material

Comment: How big is your calendar view height and calendar menu height?  What would you guess the percentage of the screen they take up? Since the card is showing up small will it scroll?

Comment: I have saved enough space for card (about half of the screen), but it still don't correctly display

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of what you have as an outcome, or share your code in a sample project? Thank you!